# what is the (If code) to check the value is the same as the variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a table with rows including the days of the week and want to make changes only for the cells 'checkIn' and 'checkOut' for the same day (if today is Sunday, make changes in the row contains 'sunday' only) (pls refer to the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqgzm.jpg)).
what will be the (if) code to do this?.
here is my code

```
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Color(0xFF8f8f8f), Color(0xFFe3e3e3)],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight),
    ),
    child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
            child: TextButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
              onPressed: () async {
                int repsonse = await locationdb().insertData(
                    "INSERT INTO 'location' ('lat','long') VALUES ('30.024960','31.210825') ");
                print(repsonse);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Detect Location',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: DataTable(
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Day')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('CheckIn')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('CheckOut')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Hrs'))
                ],
                rows: [
                  DataRow(cells: [
                    DataCell(Text('sunday')),
                    DataCell(Text('$time')),
                    DataCell(Text('$time')),
                    DataCell(Text('H'))
                  ])
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This is still kind of vague. We need more details to be able to help you.

Comment: I agree with @Jet.B.Pope that this is vague but from what I can deduce from what is currently asked in your question you need a lot more than just an if statement to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.